# Update and Delete table info with php

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

[image]

My problem is :When I press the button Delete Or Update ,they delete the information of the text boxes, and do nothing else,they do not show any error.I am new to programming, if someone can help me, I would be grateful.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English.

```
         <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "estgv15592";
        $password = "estgv155922016";
        $dbname = "estgv15592";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 


        if(isset($_POST["bt_registaraparelho"]))
        {

        $id=$_POST["id"];
           $nome=$_POST["nome"];
           $anomalias=$_POST["anomalias"];
           $datarecepcao=$_POST["datarecepcao"];
           $datareparacao=$_POST["datareparacao"];
           $dataentrega=$_POST["dataentrega"];
           $preco=$_POST["preco"];
           $estado=$_POST["estado"];


        $sql = ("UPDATE FICHA_DE_OBRA SET NOME = '$nome',ANOMALIAS = '$anomalias',CUSTO_ESTIMADO= '$preco',DATA_RECECAO= '$datarecepcao' 
        ,DATA_REPARACA= '$datareparacao',DATA_ENTREGA= '$dataentrega' ,ESTADO= '$estado' WHERE ID_FICHAOBRA = $id");


        mysqli_select_db('estgv15592');

         $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        echo "Alterado com Sucesso\n";

        mysqli_close($conn);


        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           if(isset($_POST["btn_eliminar"]))
        {
             $id=$_POST["id"];



        $sql = "DELETE FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA WHERE id='$id' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) > 0) echo 'Selected data rows Deleted';

        mysqli_select_db('estgv15592');
       $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not delete data: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";


            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        }


 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
        {

            $id = (integer) $_POST["id"];

            $query = "SELECT NOME, TELEMOVEL,ANOMALIAS,CUSTO_ESTIMADO,DATA_RECECAO, DATA_REPARACA,DATA_ENTREGA, ESTADO,
             PRECO FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA WHERE ID_FICHAOBRA = '$id' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            $details = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $nome = $details["NOME"];
            $telemovel = $details["TELEMOVEL"];
            $anomalias = $details["ANOMALIAS"];
            $custoestimado = $details["CUSTO_ESTIMADO"];
            $datarececao = $details["DATA_RECECAO"];
            $datareparacao = $details["DATA_REPARACA"];
            $dataentrega = $details["DATA_ENTREGA"];
            $estado = $details["ESTADO"];
            $preco = $details["PRECO"];
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo '<div class="absolute">';
         echo '<form id="form" method="post">';
            echo "<select name ='id'>";
            echo "<option value=''>Selecione Número ficha Obra</option>";
        echo '</div>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 


              {
              echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_FICHAOBRA'] . "'>" . $row['ID_FICHAOBRA'] . "</option>";
              }
              echo "</select>";



            $conn->close();
            ?> 


    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn">


 </div>
  <br/>

   </form>

 <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">

                <hr>


     <div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="post" autocomplete="disable" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">ID:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Nome:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Telemovel:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="telemovel" value="<?php echo $telemovel?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Anomalias:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="anomalias" value="<?php echo $anomalias;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Data Recepção:</span>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="datarecepcao" value="<?php echo $datarececao?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Data Reparação:</span>
          <input type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="" name="datareparacao" value="<?php echo $datareparacao;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Data Entrega:</span>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="dataentrega" value="<?php echo $dataentrega;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Custo Estimado:</span>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="precoestimado" value="<?php echo $custoestimado;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Estado:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="estado" value="<?php echo $estado;?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Preço:</span>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="preco" value="<?php echo $preco;?>" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>
        <input align="left" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="bt_alterar" value="Update">
        <input align="right" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="bt_eliminar" value="Delete">
    </p>
    <p
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mixing mysqli with mysql!!!

Comment: You never check for Errors, so you do not see any

Comment: your executing same query multiple times .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up everything like mysql, mysqli, Multiple connections. Please use either mysql or mysqli for whole script. There is no need to select db so many time.

Your code need some modification like
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn ); Wrong
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ); Right

Here is modified version of your code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "estgv15592";
$password = "estgv155922016";
$dbname = "estgv15592";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if(isset($_POST["bt_registaraparelho"]))
{

   $id=$_POST["id"];
   $nome=$_POST["nome"];
   $anomalias=$_POST["anomalias"];
   $datarecepcao=$_POST["datarecepcao"];
   $datareparacao=$_POST["datareparacao"];
   $dataentrega=$_POST["dataentrega"];
   $preco=$_POST["preco"];
   $estado=$_POST["estado"];

    $sql = ("UPDATE FICHA_DE_OBRA SET NOME = '$nome',ANOMALIAS = '$anomalias', CUSTO_ESTIMADO= '$preco', DATA_RECECAO= '$datarecepcao' , DATA_REPARACA= '$datareparacao', DATA_ENTREGA= '$dataentrega' , ESTADO= '$estado' WHERE ID_FICHAOBRA = $id");


    /**Not needed. You have already have a active connection */
    //mysql_select_db('estgv15592');

    $retval = $conn->query($sql);

    /**An integer greater than zero indicates the number of rows affected or retrieved. Zero indicates that no records were updated for an UPDATE statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no query has yet been executed. -1 indicates that the query returned an error.*/
    if(!$retval && $conn->affected_rows != -1 ) {  
       die('Could not update data: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }
    echo "Alterado com Sucesso\n";

    /**Not needed. Close the connection at the end*/
    mysql_close($conn);
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST["btn_eliminar"]))
{
    $id=$_POST["id"];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA WHERE id='$id' ";

    /*$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); 
        if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) echo 'Selected data rows Deleted';
    */
    /**Not needed. You have already have a active connection */
    //mysql_select_db('estgv15592');

    $retval = $conn->query($sql);

    if(!$retval && $conn->affected_rows != -1 ) {
       die('Could not delete data: ' .$mysqli->error);
    }
    echo "Deleted data successfully\n";

    //$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"]))
{

    $id = (integer) $_POST["id"];

    $query = "SELECT NOME, TELEMOVEL,ANOMALIAS,CUSTO_ESTIMADO,DATA_RECECAO, DATA_REPARACA,DATA_ENTREGA, ESTADO,
     PRECO FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA WHERE ID_FICHAOBRA = '$id' ";
    $result = $conn->query($conn, $query);

    $details = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $nome = $details["NOME"];
    $telemovel = $details["TELEMOVEL"];
    $anomalias = $details["ANOMALIAS"];
    $custoestimado = $details["CUSTO_ESTIMADO"];
    $datarececao = $details["DATA_RECECAO"];
    $datareparacao = $details["DATA_REPARACA"];
    $dataentrega = $details["DATA_ENTREGA"];
    $estado = $details["ESTADO"];
    $preco = $details["PRECO"];

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM FICHA_DE_OBRA";

$result = $conn->query($conn, $sql);
echo '<div class="absolute">';
echo '<form id="form" method="post">';
echo "<select name ='id'>";
echo "<option value=''>Selecione Número ficha Obra</option>";
echo '</div>';
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_FICHAOBRA'] . "'>" . $row['ID_FICHAOBRA'] . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

/* free result set */
$result->free();

$conn->close();
?>

<input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn">
</div>
<br/>
</form>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
<hr>
<div class="jumbotron">
<form method="post" autocomplete="disable" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">ID:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Nome:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Telemovel:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="telemovel" value="<?php echo $telemovel?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Anomalias:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="anomalias" value="<?php echo $anomalias;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Data Recepção:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="datarecepcao" value="<?php echo $datarececao?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Data Reparação:</span>
  <input type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="" name="datareparacao" value="<?php echo $datareparacao;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Data Entrega:</span>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="dataentrega" value="<?php echo $dataentrega;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Custo Estimado:</span>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="precoestimado" value="<?php echo $custoestimado;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Estado:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="estado" value="<?php echo $estado;?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Preço:</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="preco" value="<?php echo $preco;?>" />
</div>
<br>
<p>
  <input align="left" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="bt_alterar" value="Update">
  <input align="right" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="bt_eliminar" value="Delete">
</p>
<p

</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time lost, but the problem persists = (

Comment: the problem now was the name of the button.